# When shorting power leads to an unenergized bldc motor, it locks up why?

Tags: motor

Why do bldc motors or ecm motors lock up when I short two of the leads on n an unenergized motor.  I am a little stumped as to why the unenergized coils are creating a magnetic resistance.   Someone please help me to understand this.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock up"?

Comment: So, you short two leads together and then try and rotate?

Answer (score 4):

You are discovering why some of the free energy schemes don't work. Many of us, in our youth, have invented the idea of recharging an electric vehicle's batteries from a dynamo attached to the wheels. The problem, of course, is that the energy has to come from somewhere so drawing energy from the dynamo causes mechanical resistance on the dynamo shaft and this has to be overcome by the driving force.

In your case you have a short on the output of your "generator" so any motion causes a current to flow, limited only by the motor's internal resistance. Even though you are doing no useful work outside the generator the power being dissipated internally has to come from the generator shaft and this is the resistance you feel.

Answer (score 3):

It is due to Lenz's and Faraday's law.

When you spin the rotor, the magnets on the rotor cut the coils on the stator and a voltage is induced at the terminals. However, you have shorted the terminals so this voltage permit current flow around the stator. This current flowing around the stator produces a magnetic field. This magnetic field is opposing movement and thus the "lock up" you are experiencing.

Its not "locked up", just producing an opposing torque which is finite in production.